# Toggle the hidden and visible buttons on the main button through 2 sub-buttons left and right

Tags: .net, wpf

Good morning everyone, today I wonder how can I toggle the main button to show left and right in 2 secondary buttons:
i have 3 buttons : the main button is in the middle , and the left button and the secondary button are on either side , left and right , when the user clicks left or right the main button is in hidden properties then the button will show and vice versa , i have max main button of 7: PLAY , LEAVE , INSTALL , MAPS , INSTALL_BLOCK , RUN , REPAIR . , thanks

[image]

```
private void LEFT_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
      Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, (SendOrPostCallback)delegate
      {
           // EXAMPLE CODE //
      }
}
private void RIGHT_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
      Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, (SendOrPostCallback)delegate
      {
           // EXAMPLE CODE //
      }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the main button loop through Play, Leave, …?

Comment: yes I want the main button to change the hidden or visible property via 2 secondary buttons when the user clicks.

Comment: 7 main buttons are stacked on top of each other, I'm stuck here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to manage the buttons with a collection. Put all buttons inside a container like a `Grid` and name that container.

```xml
<DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Button Width="40"
            Height="40"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Click="LeftButton_Click"
            Content="l"
            DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
    <Button Width="40"
            Height="40"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Click="RightButton_Click"
            Content="r"
            DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
    <Grid x:Name="ButtonContainer"
            Width="100"
            Height="100">
        <Button Content="1" />
        <Button Content="2" />
        <Button Content="3" />
        <Button Content="4" />
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

In code behind we can query that named container for all children that are of type `Button` and store them into a list.

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly List<Button> _buttons;
    private int _activeButtonIndex = 0;

    public MainWindow( MainWindowViewModel viewModel )
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _buttons = ButtonContainer.Children.OfType<Button>().ToList();
        _buttons.ForEach( b => b.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden );
        _buttons[_activeButtonIndex].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Now it is an easy part to loop through that button list and hide the old button and make the new visible.

```cs
    private void LeftButton_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
    {
        _buttons[_activeButtonIndex].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        if ( ++_activeButtonIndex >= _buttons.Count ) _activeButtonIndex = 0;
        _buttons[_activeButtonIndex].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void RightButton_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
    {
        _buttons[_activeButtonIndex].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        if ( --_activeButtonIndex < 0 ) _activeButtonIndex = _buttons.Count - 1;
        _buttons[_activeButtonIndex].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```